# Различие между использованием var и dynamic в foreach

Tags: c#

У меня 2 вопроса:

1) Почему в 1-м `foreach` на переменной name недоступны члены `DictionaryEntry`(например, `name.Value`),ведь она принадлежит(или как правильно сказать) типу `DictionaryEntry`,а во 2-м `foreach`-всё good?

```
static void Main()
    {
        var emailLookup = new Hashtable();

        emailLookup["sbishop@contoso.com"] = "Bishop, Scott";
        emailLookup["chess@contoso.com"] = "Hell, Christian";
        emailLookup["djump@contoso.com"] = "Jump, Dan";

        foreach (var name in emailLookup)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(name);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(new string('-', 20));

        foreach (DictionaryEntry name in emailLookup)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(name);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(new string('-', 20));

        foreach (object name in emailLookup.Values)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(name);
        }

        // Delay.
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

2) Почему в нижеприведённом примере,в `foreach` при использовании `var` - нет доступа к `Key` и `Value`,а при использовании `dynamic` - есть?

```
class UserCollection
{
    public static IEnumerable Generator()
    {
        yield return new { Key = 0, Value = "Zero" };
        yield return new { Key = 1, Value = "One" };
        yield return new { Key = 2, Value = "Two" };
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        foreach (var item in UserCollection.Generator())
        {               
            Console.WriteLine("Key = {0}, Value = {1}", item.Key, item.Value);               
        }

        // Delay.
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Почему в 1-м foreach на переменной name недоступны члены DictionaryEntry(например,name.Value)

Потому что в этом случае `name` это *DictionaryEntry* упакованный в *object*. И так как у *object* нет свойств *key*, *value* они и недоступны.

Во втором `foreach` - происходит явное приведение к *DictionaryEntry*, поэтому `name` не упакованный объект, а непосредственно структура, с нужными полями.

> Почему в нижеприведённом примере,в foreach при использовании var-нет доступа к Key и Value

Потому что из функции возвращается `IEnumerable` - это нетипизированная коллекция и *item* опять является упакованным в *object*

С *dynamic* это работает потому, что проверка на существование свойств происходит не во время компиляции, а во время выполнения, так как реально возвращается объект с нужными полями, ошибки не возникает.

<sub>Больше про упаковку можно прочитать в MSDN: [Упаковка-преобразование и распаковка-преобразование](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/yz2be5wk.aspx)

Больше про использования *dynamic* можно прочитать в MSDN: [Использование типа dynamic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd264736.aspx)</sub>

Comment: Получается в foreach можно сделать DownCast к DictionaryEntry?

Comment: @Vladmes, почему `DownCast`? в данном случае скорее `unboxing`. Кроме того, по большому счету при использовании вместо `var` конкретного типа происходит попытка каста объекта полученного из коллекции к указанному типу. То есть, внутри цикла будут доступны все поля указанного класса, но при невозможности привести объект из коллекции к указанному классу произойдет какой-нибудь _InvalidCastException_ например