# Зачем тут тип dynamic?

Tags: c#

В C# можно создавать  счетчик итераций типа dynamic

```
  for (dynamic i = 0; i < 10; i++)
```

Но зачем? Т.е как я понял, сначала я таким образом я могу вести учет например с помощью int, а затем подставить туда short  - потерять при смене с int на short точность и таким образом отбросить счетчик?
Если нет, то зачем тип счетчика вообще указывать как dynamic , ведь int вполне достаточно?

Comment: В том куске, который вы привели, это не нужно. Покажите больше кода, может, будет понятнее.

Comment: @VladD Это учебный пример и в нем просто показана такая возможность - внутри цикла на экран выводится строка и все. Это сделано просто что бы продемонстрировать: "А смотрите - имеется такая возможность". Но ведь она действительно имеется. Для чего? Можете привести пример, или более удачный код? Спасибо.

Comment: @BadCats в проведенном Вами примере никакого практического смысла нет. Dynamic используется в случаях, когда заранее не известен тип возвращаемого значения, например COM. Подробнее: https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/9.1.php, https://professorweb.ru/my/csharp/assembly/level5/5_2.php и https://www.google.ru/search?q=c%23%20%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20dynamic&oq=c%23%20%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20dynamic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь подобный пример

[Различие между использованием var и dynamic в foreach](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/548728/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-var-%D0%B8-dynamic-%D0%B2-foreach)

Тип является статическим типом, но объект типа dynamic обходит проверку статического типа. В большинстве случаев он функционирует, как тип object. Во время компиляции предполагается что элементы с типом dynamic поддерживают любые операции. Поэтому разработчику не нужно следить за тем, откуда объект получает свое значение — из интерфейса API COM, из динамического языка, такого как IronPython, из объектной модели DOM HTML, из отражения или из любого другого места программы. Но если код является недействительным, во время выполнения перехватываются ошибки.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd264736.aspx

Позволяет использовать тип i как другой неявным преобразованием.