# инкапсуляция, ad hoc полиморфизм и dynamic

Tags: c#

Согласно ответу **@Grundy** на следующий вопрос :

> 2) Почему в нижеприведённом примере,в foreach при использовании var - нет доступа к Key и Value,а при использовании dynamic - есть?

оригинал вопроса:[Различие между использованием var и dynamic в foreach](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/548728/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-var-%D0%B8-dynamic-%D0%B2-foreach)

```
class UserCollection
{
    public static IEnumerable Generator()
    {
        yield return new { Key = 0, Value = "Zero" };
        yield return new { Key = 1, Value = "One" };
        yield return new { Key = 2, Value = "Two" };
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        foreach (var item in UserCollection.Generator())
        {               
            Console.WriteLine("Key = {0}, Value = {1}", item.Key, item.Value);               
        }

        // Delay.
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

> С dynamic это работает потому, что проверка на существование свойств
>   происходит не во время компиляции, а во время выполнения, так как
>   реально возвращается объект с нужными полями, ошибки не возникает.

И затрагивая вот эту тему: 
Согласно ответу @VladD на следующий вопрос :

> Метод с dynamic внутри — ещё один валидный пример параметрического полиморфизма. (Но не ad hoc, по идее.) Хотя, вызов правильного метода при использовании f((dynamic)o) — это снова ad hoc-полиморфизм.

-вот почему в заголовке вопроса я упоминаю ad hoc полиморфизм

Оригинал Вопроса:

[Чем ad hoc полиморфизм отличается от обычного полиморфизма?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/464752/%D0%A7%D0%B5%D0%BC-ad-hoc-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B0)

Вот в чем заключается мой вопрос:

Как я понял, ad hoc полиморфизм заключается в том, что именно благодаря времени проверки - и не происходит инкапсуляция?

**я спрашиваю о том, почему именно не происходит инкапсуляция - она не происходит из за времени проверки? т.е инкапсуляция не происходит из за того что проверка типов выполняется во время выполнения?**

И именно поэтому это все можно назвать ad hoc полиморфизмом?

P.s *Но это не как не вопрос про разницу ad hoc и обычного полиморфизма* - здесь я просто привел ссылку на этот вопрос в качестве первоисточника, откуда ***затрагивается***         тема ad hoc полиморфизма.

Comment: вопрос не понятен. И возможно его стоит закрыть как дубликат вопроса про разницу ad hoc и обычного полиморфизма

Comment: Переформулируйте последнее предложение. При чем здесь "инкапсуляция", и как она может "происходить"?

Comment: Это не совсем дубликат, тут я спрашиваю о том, почему именно не происходит инкапсуляция - она не происходит из за времени проверки? т.е инкапсуляция не происходит из за того что проверка типов выполняется во время выполнения?

Comment: @BadCats, что ты имеешь ввиду под _инкапсуляцией_? и почему ты решил, что _она не происходит_?

Comment: Под инкапсуляцией я имею ввиду сокрытие реализации - как парадигму ООП. А пишу что она не происходит, как раз потому что согласно ответу @VladD я понял это зависит от момента проверки типов - т.е если тип проверяется динамически, - т.е как раз потому что мы используем тип dynamic  - инкапсуляция не происходит.

Comment: какая связь между сокрытием реализации и dynamic?

Comment: Связь такая, что если мы в той же ситуации(см первую ссылку) будем использовать var - это приведет элементы коллекции к типу object, что будет upcustom - что не даст потом обратится к полям экземпляров анонимного типа - т.к мы привели их к типу object - а это прямое отражение идей инкапсуляции как сокрытия реализации

Comment: ты ошибаешься. Отредактируй вопрос так, чтобы сразу было понятно о чем ты говоришь, без проходов по ссылкам. Можешь добавить пример кода иллюстрирующий проблему о которой ты говоришь. Как тебе ответили в прошлом вопросе, `var` - это не тип, при использовании этого ключевого слова **не происходит** upcast или downcast или любой другой cast. В любом случае к инкапсуляции все это не имеет отношения.

Comment: Хорошо, отредактирую.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57491/discussion-between-grundy-and-badcats).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотрите. В вашем вопросе есть несколько неверных утверждений. Давайте попробуем пройтись по ним.

> Как я понял, ad hoc полиморфизм заключается в том, что именно благодаря времени проверки - и не происходит инкапсуляция?

Смотрите, инкапсуляция — это свойство языка держать данные и методы для работы с ними в одном общем месте (именуемом обычно «класс»). То, что при этом некоторые данные доступны для использования снаружи класса, а некоторые нет, не есть составной частью полиморфизма. Это называется «сокрытие данных/методов». Хотя [английская википедия](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)) рассматривает оба определения: в котором сокрытие считается частью инкапсуляции, и в котором это отдельная концепция.

Давайте, чтобы не создавать недоразумения, говорить о сокрытии данных/методов.

Далее, важная часть. Механизмом сокрытия данных является объявление их как `private`/`public`. То, что вы не знаете реальный тип объекта, **не является сокрытием данных**.

Пример:

```
class Test
{
    public int X;
    private int Y;
}
```

Пускай у нас есть такие переменные:

```
var     v1 = new Test();
object  v2 = new Test();
var     v3 = (object)(new Test());
object  v4 = (object)(new Test());
dynamic v5 = new Test();
dynamic v6 = (object)(new Test());
```

Какой тип этих переменных? Этот вопрос делится на два вопроса: compile-time (заявленный) тип и run-time (фактический) тип.

Фактический тип каждой из переменных — `Test`. Заявленный тип `v1` — `Test`, `v2`, `v3` и `v4` — `object`, `v5` и `v6` — `dynamic`.

У переменной `v1` вы можете получить доступ к полю `X` и не можете к полю `Y` именно вследствие работы *сокрытия данных*: это `private`-поле.

У переменных `v2`, `v3` и `v4` вы не можете получить доступ к полю `X` не из-за сокрытия данных, а из-за того, что вы не видите на этапе компиляции её фактический тип. Но вы можете получить этот доступ, выполнив преобразование типов:

```
((Test)v2).X = 1;
```

Доступ к полю `Y` вы не можете получить даже при преобразовании типов.

С переменными `v5` и `v6` тоже всё просто. Они ведут себя во время выполнения так, как будто бы заявленный тип совпадает с фактическим. То есть снова-таки вы можете получить доступ к полю `X`, но не к полю `Y`.

---

Таким образом, мы видим, что *сокрытие данных* (то есть, возможность получить доступ к `X` и невозможность к `Y`) работает всегда, независимо от полиморфных средств языка.

> я спрашиваю о том, почему именно не происходит инкапсуляция - она не происходит из за времени проверки? т.е инкапсуляция не происходит из за того что проверка типов выполняется во время выполнения?

Сокрытие данных, как вы видели, происходит, в любом случае. Проверка типов во время выполнения для `dynamic` лишь делает преобразование к нужному типу за вас, но не открывает доступ к закрытым данным.